# Getting list of files in a db2 database

Tags: db2

I have an application which connects to db2 and i am able to connect to the database and update data on any table/file in the database. Now want to retrive a list of the tables in a specific library (e.g qgpl) like i would use the Directory.GetFiles .
I am connecting via OleDb

Comment: DB2 for OS/X or DB2 for Windows or DB2 for Unix?

Comment: That actually sounds like DB2 for System i (AS/400): _"library (e.g. qgpl)"_

Comment: Yes it is DB2 for System i(AS400)

Comment: You'd have a much easier time using SQL and grabbing data from the information schema.  Although I have no clue how multi-record files present in either one.... what is it you want this information for?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse. I need the user to select a payment file for processing. This filenames for this start with a BT. If i can get a list of the files in the library then i will simply filter off to get the BT file. User can then select a file to process via combobox. I have resorted to request the user having to type the filename via textbox but this is not an elegant way to do it